# Show $1+z=2\cos \frac{1}{2} x(\cos \frac{1}{2}x +i \sin \frac{1}{2}x)$, where $z=\cos x+i \sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $z=\cos x+i \sin x$. Show that

> $$1+z=2\cos \frac{1}{2} x(\cos \frac{1}{2}x +i \sin \frac{1}{2}x)$$

Comment: Did you know how to use double-Angle identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\cos x&=&2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-1\\
\sin x&=&2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2},
\end{eqnarray}
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
1+z&=&1+\cos x+i\sin x\\
&=&1+\Big(2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-1\Big)+i\Big(2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}\Big)\\
&=&2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+2i\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}\\
&=&2\cos\frac{x}{2}\Big(\cos\frac{x}{2}+i\sin\frac{x}{2}\Big)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: +1 for the concise answer. Just wondering, is there any particular use for this identity in complex variables, or is it just a nice exercise?

Comment: @imranfat it's a part of a series question

Answer (score 2):

That identity has a rather simple geometric interpretation. Consider the following diagram:

[image: pic]

where $x$ is the red angle and

\begin{align}
z &= \cos x + i\cdot\sin x, \\
m &= \cos \frac{x}{2} + i\cdot\sin \frac{x}{2}, \\
n &= m \cdot \cos\frac{x}{2}.
\end{align}

In other words, $z$ is any point with $|z| = 1$, and $x$ is the angle it forms with line $01$. Point $m$ indicates the bisector of $x$ and $n$ is the orthogonal projection of $1$ onto line $0m$ (starting at $0$ we would need to go in the direction of $m$ for $\cos\frac{x}{2}$). That happens to be the orthogonal projection of $z$ onto $0m$ and thus also an intersection of segments $0m$ and $1z$.
We want to prove that $2\cdot n$ and $z+1$ represent the same point.

Observe, that because $|z|=1$, $\{0, 1, z, z+1\}$ constitute four corners of a [rhombus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus) in which bisectors are the diagonals, what implies that $0m$ actually passes through $z+1$.

Now we only need to prove that $|2\cdot n| = |z+1|$. But that is also true, because $n$ happens to be at the intersection of diagonals, which is also their midpoint.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$